# MySQL subquery using INSTR

Tags: mysql, subquery

The query below will select all of the `name` records from table 1, which are NOT IN table 2:

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM t1
WHERE t1.name NOT IN (SELECT t2.name from t2)
```

This works fine for complete matches of the `name` field, but it does not work for partial matches.  How can I modify the query so that it will select only the `name` records from table 1 where ***no part*** of the `name` appeals in table 2?

I suspect that the answer is going to involve using INSTR, but I'm not sure of the syntax.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN will do the job

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  name VARCHAR(10);
)

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  name VARCHAR(10);
)

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES
( 'x123' ),
( 'y123' ),
( 'z123' );


INSERT INTO test2 VALUES
( '123' ),
( '423' ),
( '23' );

SELECT t1.name, t2.name 
   FROM test1 t1
   JOIN test2 t2
       ON INSTR(t1.name, t2.name ) = 0
ORDER BY t1.name;
```

Comment: Change my query to "ON INSTR(t1.name, t2.name ) = 0" to build NOT found like your query is

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and the edit @twyly.  I was originally playing with your > 0 answer, and that was throwing me for a loop.  Now with = 0, it is working fine.  Cheers.